# Finding MAX id from table with conditions

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

There is a table with columns: **id**, **name**, **age**.
I need to find the max value of id and display **name** and **id**, where name starts with just **A**.
I used the query below to get the results, but this query doesn't return the unique row.
Its will retrieve from DB all rows where name start with, for example **A**, and all id's will be listed in the results set. My query HQL is:

```
SELECT t.name, MAX(t.id) 
FROM table t 
WHERE t.name LIKE 'A%' AND t.age= :age
GROUP BY t.name
```

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

The WHERE clause is filtering your data by the criteria you want, but it's SELECT and GROUPING by the name instead of just the first letter.

So what you need to do is 2 steps. First report the Max(ID) that satisfies your criteria. Next, you'll want to join that ID back to the data to retrieve the name.

So, this is your first into into the wonderful world of subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
table t1
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id
  FROM table
  WHERE name LIKE 'A%' AND age= :age
) AS toprecord
ON t1.id = toprecord.max_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t 
WHERE t.name LIKE 'A%' AND t.age= :age
ORDER BY t.id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```